# How are APIs and interfaces (object types) made available to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure I'll be asking some things incorrectly because of my lack of understanding of how JavaScript works but here goes....

I'm extremely frustrated because so far I have not found any literature that really explains how this is done.  I've even looked at books on compilers and nothing seems to be related to what I'm asking here.

I was looking at web apis https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API and was curios as how these are made available to JavaScript under the hood.  Let me clarify my thoughts.

JavaScript has no Console object, or Window object (not 100% sure on this one), or DOM Object, etc....  The V8 engine just compiles and makes machine code, but I can't find out how for example a console object is made available to javascript.   Why can I do console.log();  This is the same as node.js, there is no window object there....but there are also api's available in node.js, and they aren't part of JavaScript.

Are these web api's c++ api/code?  If so, how does the browser environment make them available to JavaScript, and why am I able to use JavaScript syntax to work with them?

Are there any books or resources available that would help me learn about this?  Compiler books don't seem to have anything like this, nor do systems programming books.  I don't even know the terms to look for?  Run Time Environment(doesn't seem right, I've looked these up), programming environment, where the hell did Ryan Dahl, or the Chrome people, or the people that make these environments surrounding languages learn this stuff?

-Thanks.

Comment: An environment can provide a context to an embedded language—that’s all it is. The implementation of context objects is irrelevant; could be C, C++, JS, etc. When JS talks to native code it’s through some form of FFI.

Comment: If you search for “embedded JS engine” or similar you’ll find a variety of approaches and options that’ll let you try out any number of solutions.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I can now investigate Foreign Function Interfaces...so are you saying JS talks to for example C++ through a FFE?  Is JavaScript the embedded language in this case?  I don't know what a context is, I'll have to look that up, thanks!

Comment: JavaScript environments commonly have a set of objects – such as `window` in a web browser context – which serve as interfaces to the underlying host software.  You manipulate them as you would any other JavaScript object, but they are in fact "special."  Other languages do the same thing:  there are objects which are public and special.  When you manipulate them, the host software gets called by the language interpreter or runtime.